# Get distinct related data from arrays of ObjectIds on each document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have a collection of **Organizations** like so:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Organization 1",
        "locations": [
            "5b0096f064386ef34a5118d0", // Location 1
            "5b0096f064386ef34a5118d2" // Location 2
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Organization 2",
        "locations": [
            "5b0096f064386ef34a5118d0" // Location 1
        ]
    }
    // ~1,000 organizations ...
]
```

and a collection of **Locations** like so:

```
[
    {
        // Location 1
        "_id": "5b0096f064386ef34a5118d0",
        "state": "AK",
        "city": "Adak"
    },
    {
        // Location 2
        "_id": "5b0096f064386ef34a5118d2",
        "state": "AK",
        "city": "Akhiok"
    },
    // ~36,000 locations ...
    {
        // Location 3
        "_id": "5b0096f064386ef34a51a63e",
        "state": "WY",
        "city": "Yoder"
    }
]
```

Each **Organization** has an array of location ids (which reference the **Location** collection).

I want to be able to get a list of distinct "used"/referenced Locations, with populated data (like city and state).

For example, in the above scenario I'd like to get back:

```
[
    {
        // Location 1
        "_id": "5b0096f064386ef34a5118d0",
        "state": "AK",
        "city": "Adak"
    },
    {
        // Location 2
        "_id": "5b0096f064386ef34a5118d2",
        "state": "AK",
        "city": "Akhiok"
    }
]
```

...since Location 1 and Location 2 are the only ones that are actually referenced.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: It they are "actually referenced" then simply `Organization.distinct("locations")` will actually return the "distinct list" of the `ObjectId` values. Keep in mind that even this "list" is still "technically" a BSON Object with the same 16MB constraint of everything else. So you could do that as a separate query and then fetch the matching items from the "locations" collection. For anything else you "could" `$group` the distinct entries and `$lookup` the related detail, but there would be some overhead to that. It really depends on what you want the results for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother trying to do it in a single query. You'll have async challenges doing this:

```
    MongoOrganization.findById(org_id, function (error, org) {
      if (error) res.send(error);

      let locations;

      MongoLocations.find({'_id': { $in: org.locations } }, function (err, locs) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        locations = locs;
      })

      org.locations = locations;

      res.json(org);
    })
```

Instead get the orgs:

```
MongoOrganization.findById(org_id, function (error, org) {
   if (error) res.send(error);
   res.json(org);
})
```

Then make a second call to get the locations:

```
MongoLocations.find({'_id': { $in: org.locations } }, function (err, locations) {
   if (err) res.send(err);
   res.json(locations);
})
```

and then copy over the string array with your object array

Comment: This answer combined with Neil Lunn's comment helped me come to a solution. I retrieved the distinct Location ObjectId's (`locationIds`) with `OrganizationModel.distinct('locations')` and then queried the Location model with `LocationModel.find({ _id: { $in: locationIds } })` to grab entire Location objects.